# Chunk method not working for blade Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have to display my results as chunks of five in blade and this is my code:

```
 <?php
                        $iterationNo = 0;
                        ?>
                        @foreach($purchase->orders as $order)
                        @foreach($order->items->chunk(5) as $item)

                        <tr style="font-size: 10pt;">
                            <td style="padding: 16px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top;">
                                <?php
                                $iterationNo = $iterationNo + 1;

                                ?>
                                {{ $iterationNo }}
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 16px; vertical-align: top;">
                                {{ $item->product->parentProduct->product_code }}
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 6px; vertical-align: top;">
                                <table>
                                    <tr style="font-size: 10pt;">
                                        <td style="padding: 4px; vertical-align: top;">
                                            <img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $item->product->parentProduct->images[0]->path . '/' . $item->product->parentProduct->images[0]->filename) }}" alt="{{ $item->product->parentProduct->name }}" style="width: 105px; height: 90px; border-radius: 10px;">
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="padding: 14px; vertical-align: top;">
                                            <p style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                                {{ $item->quantity }} x {{ $item->product->parentProduct->name }}
                                            </p>
                                            <p style="margin: 0;">
                                                @if(array_key_exists('product_color_name', $item->product_information))
                                                Color: {{ $item->product_information['product_color_name'] }}
                                                @endif
                                                @if(array_key_exists('product_size', $item->product_information))
                                                Color Temperature: {{ $item->product_information['product_size'] }}
                                                @endif
                                                @if(array_key_exists('product_temperature', $item->product_information))
                                                Color Temperature: {{ $item->product_information['product_temperature'] }}
                                                @endif
                                            </p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 16px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top;">
                                {{ $item->quantity }}
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 16px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top;">
                                {{ $item->product->getDecimalPrice() }}
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 16px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top;">
                                {{ number_format(($item->subtotal_price / 100), 2) }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        @endforeach
                        @endforeach
                    </table>
```

And it shows error:

> Property [product] does not exist in this collection instance.

Not sure why this happens if I use `chunk()`. Tried replacing it with `take()` and it doesn't show the correct results either.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I order to assist you better and clearly understand your issue, you need to provide more details , what is the structure of your $purchase->orders data looks like , what have you properly build your models eloquent relationship because from your  error i can see that you are calling a product relationship $item->product

Answer (score 0):

The chunk method returns you array like this: 
`[collection([item1, item2, item3...]), collection([itemx, itemy, itemz...])]` 
For that reason your $item gets an collection with first 5 items.

You have to add one more foreach inside to iterate through those chunked items

```
foreach($order->items->chunk(5) as $items) {
    foreach($items as $item) {
        //magic inside
    }
}
```

Comment: If my collection has say 10 different items. My chunk(5) shall take first 5 items and output them, how do I get the chunk 6th to 10th items for my next page?

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work at all. It still shows all 6 items.